# Appium Inspector not finding all elements in an iOS native app

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, appium

I am trying to use the Appium 1.2.2 Inspector on a real iOS device running a native app, but I cannot get the full source of the page. Basically my app is displaying an authentication screen, but the Appium Inspector only detects 2 UIAWindows, the 1st one contains all the elements related to the status bar, but the 2nd one (the real application window) only contains an UIAElement.

I tried to use the C# driver to retrieve the page source, and this is what the server returns (basically what I described, 2 windows, the status bars elements in one of the window, and a single UIAElement in the other) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AppiumAUT>
    <UIAApplication name="App" label="App" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0" x="0" y="20" width="320" height="460">
        <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="480">
            <UIAElement name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/0/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="568">
            </UIAElement>
        </UIAWindow>
        <UIAWindow name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="480">
            <UIAStatusBar name="" label="" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="" path="/0/1/0" x="0" y="0" width="320" height="20">
                <UIAElement name="Réseau indisp." label="Réseau indisp." value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Balayez l’écran vers le bas avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de notifications., Balayer vers le haut avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de contrôle, Touchez deux fois l’écran pour faire défiler vers le haut" path="/0/1/0/0" x="6" y="0" width="83" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="3 sur 3 barres Wi-Fi" label="3 sur 3 barres Wi-Fi" value="Wifi" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Balayez l’écran vers le bas avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de notifications., Balayer vers le haut avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de contrôle, Touchez deux fois l’écran pour faire défiler vers le haut" path="/0/1/0/1" x="94" y="0" width="13" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="5:52 PM" label="5:52 PM" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Balayez l’écran vers le bas avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de notifications., Balayer vers le haut avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de contrôle, Touchez deux fois l’écran pour faire défiler vers le haut" path="/0/1/0/2" x="137" y="0" width="47" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
                <UIAElement name="Charge de la batterie : 100%, Alimentation en courant alternatif" label="Charge de la batterie : 100%, Alimentation en courant alternatif" value="" dom="" enabled="true" valid="true" visible="true" hint="Balayez l’écran vers le bas avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de notifications., Balayer vers le haut avec trois doigts pour afficher le centre de contrôle, Touchez deux fois l’écran pour faire défiler vers le haut" path="/0/1/0/3" x="282" y="0" width="33" height="20">
                </UIAElement>
            </UIAStatusBar>
        </UIAWindow>
    </UIAApplication>
</AppiumAUT>
```

Did I miss something?

Also, I would like to try with Appium 1.3, but how do you update appium when you have installed it using the .dmg ?

Edit: I forgot one detail: I use the Reveal app, and it is able to detect all the elements (so this is really an appium inspector and/or server bug)

Edit2: One more thing I noticed, the inspector correctly worked with another app.

Comment: Does the screen has native UI elements?

Comment: When I started Appium app. I got dialog box stating Appium new version is available. On Mac, you can click on Appium -> Select "Check for Update"

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem with our application. It has tooltips which were detected by Appium as UIAElements, but our developer said they have text. I guess it happens when elements are being displayed using certain ways, e.g. iOS drawing library. I had to workaround it by selecting UIAElement that has no name.